# query to Get sum of two different items that is mapped onto same code

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, mapping

I have this Inventory table for Rooms :

| dtm | hotelid | roomcode | intqty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-01-04 | 23 | svr | 9 |
| 2000-01-04 | 23 | ovb | 9 |

this is my mapping table :

| hotelid | roomcode1 | roomcode2 | externalroom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | svr | ovb | 023 |

I am trying to get the sum of intqty on the inventory table above for both room on same date:
This is what i have so far :

```
select
    a.dtm as InvDate,
    a.intResortID as ResortId,
    a.strRoomType as RoomType,
    sUM(a.intQty) as InvCount,
    am.externalRoomId
from
    dbo.tblAvailable c
    join dbo.tblAvailable a on a.dtm = c.dtm
       and a.intResortID = c.intResortID
       and a.strRoomType = c.strRoomType
    join dbo.tblResorts r on r.intResortID = a.intResortID
    join bbtest.externalResortMap arm on arm.ResortID = a.intResortID
    join bbtest.externalRoomMap am on am.RoomId = a.strRoomType
group by
    a.dtm,
    a.intResortID,
    a.strRoomType,
    a.intQty,
    am.externalRoomId
order by
    invDate;
```

The expected result is:

| Invdate | ResortId | RoomType | InvCount | externalRoomId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-01-04 | 23 | svr | 18 | 023 |

Query output :

| Invdate | ResortId | RoomType | InvCount | externalRoomId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-01-04 | 23 | svr | 9 | 023 |
| 2000-01-04 | 23 | ovb | 9 | 023 |

Comment: What is the expected result ?

Comment: what;s the name of mapping table? and which one is your room  table?

Comment: i have added the expected result @Squirrel

Comment: the mapping table name is bbtest.externalRoomMap @eshirvana main table is the first one tblAvailable

Comment: Why are you joining `tblAvailable` with itself ?

Comment: sorry i remove the changes tracking on that one so it detect any changes on that tblavailable table  what i am trying to achieve is how i can get the sum of intqty for those two room code which on are on the same row on the mapping table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure why you are join to tblAvailable twice , but If i didn't make any mistake , here is what you need to do :

```
select
    a.dtm as InvDate,
    a.intResortID as ResortId,
    am.RoomId_1 as RoomType,
    sum(a.intQty) as InvCount,
    am.externalRoomId
from
    dbo.tblAvailable a 
    join dbo.tblResorts r on r.intResortID = a.intResortID
    join bbtest.externalResortMap arm on arm.ResortID = a.intResortID
    join bbtest.externalRoomMap am 
       on a.strRoomType in (am.RoomId_1 ,am.RoomId_2)
group by
    a.dtm,
    a.intResortID,
    am.RoomId_1,   
    am.externalRoomId
order by
    invDate;
```

Comment: thanks what it did is it get the am.RoomId_2 on the final result if the am.RoomId_2 InvCount can be added to the am.RoomId_1 InvCount as well

Comment: @steifmaster maybe there is a missing condition like hotelid , ( ... and  a.hotelid = am.hotelid ) , show me the output of my query

Comment: i have added the output at the bottom of the question title : Query output :  @eshirvana

Comment: oh ok , replace strRoomType with RoomId_1 and you should be ok , see updated asnwer

Comment: also seems like you don't need to join bbtest.externalResortMap either , I''m not sure if it serves any filtering purpose or not. if not you can remove that join

Comment: please can you look into this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67410316/change-tracking-for-rows-should-get-results-also-for-other-row-not-affected-but